# How to run a "Packahe Visible Class"

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I have a GUI I'm working on and there is a blue triangle next to the 'J' icon in the package explorer, I looked this up and only found the green C icon with the blue triangle and it says that it means the package is visible, the link for reference...

http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsptopic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

What does this mean and how do I fix it so the program runs.

Comment: Please post a small example of your code and describe what happens when you try to run it!

Comment: That is a class Constructor which has 'package' visibility. It can only be used be another class in the same package.